# How to automatically insert date and time into sql table

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, time

I've created a table name `EventLog7` in SQL Server 2008 :

```
create table EventLog7(
    EventId int not null identity(1,1),
    EventDate datetimeconstraint DF_myDate DEFAULT (getdate()), 
    ObjectId varchar(50),
    Name varchar(50),
    Value varchar (50)
)
```

In NetBeans, there are three jtextfields which help to insert data into EventLog SQL Table (ObjectId, Name, Value) when I press the button.
Mentioned below action button code:

```
 String objectid=jTextField1.getText();
 String value=jTextField2.getText();
 String name=jTextField3.getText();           
 try{
     DoConnect();
     st=conn.createStatement();         
     String sql = "insert into EventLog7 values('"+objectid+"','"+name+"','"+value+"')";
     pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
     pst.execute();
     rs=st.executeQuery("select * from EventLog7");               
     jTable1.setModel(net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
 }
 catch(Exception e){
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
 }
```

So, i want that when I insert values of ObjectId,Name,Value in three jtextfiles then Sql table will insert automatically date and time with these data.

But according to my code, it's showing error

> Column names or number of supplied values does not match table definition

So please provide me right way.

Comment: Do **NOT** concatenate input into SQL statements like that. Learn how to properly use a `PreparedStatement` and pass values through `ResultSet.setInt()` or `setString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String sql = "insert into EventLog7 values('"+objectid+"','"+name+"','"+value+"')";
```

line will be

```
String sql = "insert into EventLog7(ObjectId, Name, Value, EventDate) values('"+objectid+"','"+name+"','"+value+"',GETDATE())";
```

I do not know how the IDs is generated sql-server , you may need to set it as well if that is not auto assign/increment.

*And I can say this is not secure, you need to use `?`s instead of your variables and use set methods to set them as  a_horse_with_no_name reminds.* Use what I suggested only for mitigating the error you have now.

Comment: i inserted your code then it's showing error incorrect syntax near 'battery' kindly provide me complete action button code

Comment: your code does not have something like `battery` in it , is it different than what you asked

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: See the updated query, I forgot the `'`s , now they are there

Comment: Please Up or accept the answer it helps you. Thanks.